# Sequential processing of multi-threaded results

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, parallel-processing, fork-join

I am setting up a Spring Boot application (*DAO* pattern with `@Repositories`) where I am attempting to write a `@Service` to asynchronously pull data from a database in multiple threads and merge-process the incoming payloads sequentially, preferably on arrival.

The goal is to utilize parallel database access for requests where multiple non-overlapping sets of filter conditions need to be queried individually, but post-processed (transformed, e.g. aggregated) into a combined result.

Being rather new to Java, and coming from Golang and its comparably trivial syntax for multi-threading and task-communication, I struggle to identify a preferable API in Java and Spring Boot - or determine if this approach is even favorable to begin with.

---

#### Question:

Given

- a **Controller**:

  ```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/api")
  public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/processing")
    public DeferredResult<MyResult> myHandler(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
        DeferredResult<MyResult> myDeferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        myService.myProcessing(myRequest, myDeferredResult);

        return myDeferredResult;
  }
  ```
- a **Service**:

  ```
  import com.acme.parallel.util.MyDataTransformer

  @Service
  public class MyServiceImpl implementing MyService {

    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public void myProcessing(MyRequest myRequest, MyDeferredResult myDeferredResult) {
      MyDataTransformer myDataTransformer = new MyDataTransformer();

      /* PLACEHOLDER CODE
      for (MyFilter myFilter : myRequest.getMyFilterList()) {
        // MyPartialResult myPartialResult = myRepository.myAsyncQuery(myFilter);

        // myDataTransformer.transformMyPartialResult(myPartialResult);
      }
      */

      myDeferredResult.setResult(myDataTransformer.getMyResult());
    }
  }
  ```
- a **Repository**:

  ```
  @Repository
  public class MyRepository {

    public MyPartialResult myAsyncQuery(MyFilter myFilter) {
      // for the sake of an example
      return new MyPartialResult(myFilter, TakesSomeAmountOfTimeToQUery.TRUE);
    }
  }
  ```
- as well as a **MyDataTransformer** helper class:

  ```
  public class MyDataTransformer {

    private final MyResult myResult = new MyResult();  // e.g. a Map

    public void transformMyPartialResult(MyPartialResult myPartialResult) {
      /* PLACEHOLDER CODE
      this.myResult.transformAndMergeIntoMe(myPartialResult);
      */
    }
  }
  ```

how can I implement

- the `MyService.myProcessing` method asynchronously and multi-threaded, and
- the `MyDataTransformer.transformMyPartialResult` method sequential/thread-safe
- (or redesign the above)

most performantly, to merge incoming `MyPartialResult` into one single `MyResult`?

---

#### Attempts:

The easiest solution *seems* to be to skip the *"on arrival"* part, and a commonly preferred implementation might e.g. be:

```
public void myProcessing(MyRequest myRequest, MyDeferredResult myDeferredResult) {
  MyDataTransformer myDataTransformer = new MyDataTransformer();
  
  List<CompletableFuture<myPartialResult>> myPartialResultFutures = new ArrayList<>();

  for (MyFilter myFilter : myRequest.getMyFilterList()) {     // Stream is the way they say, but I like for
    myPartialResultFutures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myRepository.myAsyncQuery(myFilter));
  }

  myPartialResultFutures.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .map(myDataTransformer::transformMyPartialResult);
      
  myDeferredResult.setResult(myDataTransformer.getMyResult());
}
```

However, if feasible I'd like to benefit from sequentially processing incoming payloads *when they arrive*, so I am currently experimenting with something like this:

```
public void myProcessing(MyRequest myRequest, MyDeferredResult myDeferredResult) {
  MyDataTransformer myDataTransformer = new MyDataTransformer();
  
  List<CompletableFuture<myPartialResult>> myPartialResultFutures = new ArrayList<>();

  for (MyFilter myFilter : myRequest.getMyFilterList()) {
    myPartialResultFutures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myRepository.myAsyncQuery(myFilter).thenAccept(myDataTransformer::transformMyPartialResult));
  }

  myPartialResultFutures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
      
  myDeferredResult.setResult(myDataTransformer.getMyResult());
}
```

but I don't understand if I need to implement any thread-safety protocols when calling `myDataTransformer.transformMyPartialResult`, and how - or if this even makes sense, performance-wise.

---

**Update:**

Based on the assumption that

- `myRepository.myAsyncQuery` takes slightly varying amounts of time, and
- `myDataTransformer.transformMyPartialResult` taking an ever increasing amount of time each call

implementing a ***thread-safe/atomic type/Object***, e.g. a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
public class MyDataTransformer {

  private final ConcurrentMap<K, V> myResult = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();

  public void transformMyPartialResult(MyPartialResult myPartialResult) {
    myPartialResult.myRows.stream()
      .map((row) -> this.myResult.merge(row[0], row[1], Integer::sum)));
  }
}
```

into the ***latter** Attempt* (processing *"on arrival"*):

```
public void myProcessing(MyRequest myRequest, MyDeferredResult myDeferredResult) {
  MyDataTransformer myDataTransformer = new MyDataTransformer();
  
  List<CompletableFuture<myPartialResult>> myPartialResultFutures = new ArrayList<>();

  for (MyFilter myFilter : myRequest.getMyFilterList()) {
    myPartialResultFutures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myRepository.myAsyncQuery(myFilter).thenAccept(myDataTransformer::transformMyPartialResult));
  }

  myPartialResultFutures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
      
  myDeferredResult.setResult(myDataTransformer.getMyResult());
}
```

***is up to one order of magnitude faster*** than waiting on all threads first, even with atomicity protocol overhead.

---

Now, this *may* have been obvious (not ultimately, though, as async/multi-threaded processing is by far not always the better choice), and I am glad this approach is a valid choice.

What remains is what looks to me like a hacky, flexibility lacking solution - or at least an ugly one. **Is there a better approach?**

Answer (score 1):

We want to process the query result as soon as it is available so `thenApply`.Here the thread querying database might immediately work on data transformation unlike in approaches mentioned, and finally the partailResult of the query could be merged in one reduce operation.

```
    public static void service() {
        //myRequest.getMyFilterList()
        List<Integer> inputList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        List<CompletableFuture<PartialResultTransformed>> partialProcessedResult = inputList.stream()
                .map(input -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.query(input)))
                .map(future -> future.thenApply(queryResult -> datatransformer.transform(queryResult)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<PartialResultTransformed> allPartialResult = partialProcessedResult.stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::join) //todo:handle exception scenario
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // final transformation of partial results
        //mergePartailResults;
       /* allPartialResult.stream()
                        .reduce();*/
    }
```